# cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone but it is not a real mistake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

I have different variants of some function, that are choosed by preprocessor definition

```cpp
    #if defined(V2)
        bool getAICoord(TTT_Game& game) {
    
            //
            // 4x4 field
            //
    
            return false;
        }
    #elif defined(V3)
        bool getAICoord(TTT_Game& game) {
    
            //
            // renju field
            //
    
            return false;
        }
    #else // V1 
        bool getAICoord(TTT_Game& game) {
            // some code
            return false;
        }
    #endif
```

And it compiles well, but IntelliSense gives me error

`cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone`

I know, that it is not perfect, but is there any way to exclude this one function from its checklist or something like this?

Comment: I have only one definition of this type: `#define V1`. Also my directives are bilt in the way to choose only one of the variants, as there are `#elif`s not separate `#if`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could workaround this error by only typing the function signature once and using the preprocessor definitions on the body of the function; e.g.

```
bool getAICoord(TTT_Game& game) {
#if defined(V2)
    //
    // 4x4 field
    //
    return false;
#elif defined(V3)
    //
    // renju field
    //
    return false;
#else // V1
    // some code
    return false;
#endif
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but as for me it would look more complex this way

Comment: I think about wrap function variant. Like if I had functions like AI_V1, AI_V2 and one wrap function, that would choose one of them depending on preprocessor directive.

Comment: If you say so. This version makes it much more obvious (to me) that only the body of the function changes and that there is no difference to the function signature.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor macros notoriously confuse IDEs, as they are pure text transformation of the code, instead of being part of the language itself.

Instead of using macros, `if constexpr` lets you do conditional compilation as part of the language itself instead of doing it as a preprocessor step:

This has a number of advantages:

- It confuses IDEs a lot less.
- All code paths get syntactical validation, even when excluded.

```
constexpr int kVersion = SOME_DEFINE;

bool getAICoord(TTT_Game& game) {
  if constexpr(kVersion == 3) {
      //...    
  } else if constexpr(kVersion == 2) {
      //...
  } else {
      //...
  }
}
```

Comment: `if constexpr` is rarely the solution if the condition is not dependent on a template, because it's essentially `if constexpr (false)`, which means it's not actually removed. Say some function definitions are only available with certain values of `kVersion` (or some type definitions are different), then this will fail to compile

Comment: This is just a different form of syntactic sugar. There is nothing fundamentally different here that would "confuse" the IDE any more or less.

IDEs sometimes try to be helpful by graying out code that is excluded by #ifdefs. They don't seem to try that just yet with if constexpr (and might never). IDEs may be less confused with if constexpr only because they make no attempt to be helpful.

Comment: That second bullet point can just as easily be a drawback. If I'm choosing between implementing a function that uses Windows OS calls and implementing it using Unix (variants) OS calls I don't want to have to write code so that both versions are valid under both OS's.